# Twilio client.messages.stream() returning infinite results?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

so I know my Twilio account has sent upwards of 50,000 texts. However, when I run the following:

```
for item in client.messages.stream():
     i+=1
     lst.append([item.body.replace('|',''),item.from_,item.date_sent])
     if i % 100 == 0:
          print(i)
```

It just keeps running and running. I was originally using `client.messages.list`, but that hit my 1 minute, then 5 minute, then 10 minute timeout in lambda, so I decided to debug locally, and run the above. I stopped it after it had gotten to 230,000, which is many multiple more messages than we've actually sent.

I don't quite know why it's doing that? The docs don't say anything about this? I can't find in the docs either a way to tell the stream to move on, if what it's doing is just returning the same page over and over.

It doesn't *appear* to be returning the same page, though - when I print the message body for the hundredth one it changes every so often.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-python/7.8.0/docs/source/_rst/twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.message.html#twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.message.MessageList

Answer (score 0):

`client.messages.stream():` will return all the messages you have *sent* as well as *received*.

You can [filter the list](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources) by the number the number a message was sent from, if you are only looking to retrieve your outbound messages.

If you are looking to limit the results you are getting, you can set a `limit`. If you want to speed long requests like this up, you can increase the `pageSize` to a 1000 (default is 50).